# Unexpected token argument in render method

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to start Express.js server with react application that I downloaded, but when I do npm start on my server there is error

```
ERROR in ./src/app.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:7)
  4 | import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
  5 |
> 6 | render(<div>Place your application here</div>, document.getElementById('app-root'));
```

Why would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working by settings presets in webpack.config: 
`presets:['es2015','react']` - for error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`
and `npm install babel-preset-react` + `babel-preset-es2015`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  < div > Place your application here < /div>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Same error and its still saying that error is in <div> string

Comment: `import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';


ReactDOM.render(<div>Place your application here</div>, document.getElementById('app-root'));`

Comment: Thanks, it worked partly, but div where should text render is empty. Console says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: Have you installed babel-loader. This seems to be the problem of browser not recognizing es6